# How does one remove the bound version of an event handler?

Tags: javascript, binding, event-handling, dom-events

I've a problem with my binding event, I would like to remove each event when change event is fired. It's working fine without a loop.

```js
this.objectInstance.on('selected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        this.test = this.fontFamilyHandler.bind(this, el.getAttribute('id'));
        el.addEventListener('change', this.test);
    }) 
});

this.objectInstance.on('deselected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        el.removeEventListener('change', this.test);
    })
});

fontFamilyHandler = (key, evt) => {
    this.objectInstance.set(key, evt.target.value);
    this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

Do you have any idea why it's doesn't work ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, you should provide a [mre] and describe exactly how the code fails. You seem to keep overwriting `this.test`, so you're setting a bunch of new functions as event handlers, but your deselected code tries to remove the last function from all elements I guess. You probably have to store references to all functions, like `this.test[el.getAttribute('id')]`

Comment: One needs to see surrounding code in order to get an understanding of the actual `this` the OP is dealing with ... I'm especially curious about `fontFamilyHandler = (key, evt) => { /* ... */ }` where this function floats freely versus  line 3 where all of a sudden one sees `this.fontFamilyHandler.bind(this, el.getAttribute('id'));`

Comment: To prevent guessing, where are the "select" and "deselect" events coming from (can you add a tag for it or mention it in the question)? Clarifying "it doesn't work" could help as well - "is the computer plugged in and powered on" is just the start of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"One needs to see surrounding code in order to get an understanding of the actual `this` the OP is dealing with ... I'm especially curious about `fontFamilyHandler = (key, evt) => { /* ... */ }` where this function floats freely versus line 3 where all of a sudden one sees `this.fontFamilyHandler.bind(this, el.getAttribute('id'));`"*

Until then the next provided answer assumes kind of a class syntax/system for a hypothetical `MyType` class.

Of cause the binding as with ...

```
this.fontFamilyHandler.bind(this, el.getAttribute('id'));
```

... is not necessary at all because the OP already does access the `event.target` within this handler which equals the above `el` ...

```
fontFamilyHandler = (key, evt) => {
  this.objectInstance.set(key, evt.target.value);
  this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

Thus, binding each element's `id` is not necessary since this property can be accessed via `evt.target.id` as much as the value already via `evt.target.value`.

In the end the code will boil down to something much more readable like ...

```
//class MyType {
//  constructor() {
//    this.objectInstance = { on: () => {} };

    this.objectInstance.on('selected', () => document
      .querySelectorAll('select')
      .forEach(el =>
        el.addEventListener('change', this.fontFamilyHandler)
      )
    );
    this.objectInstance.on('deselected', () => document
      .querySelectorAll('select')
      .forEach(el =>
        el.removeEventListener('change', this.fontFamilyHandler)
      )
    );

    this.fontFamilyHandler = ({ target }) => {
      this.objectInstance.set(target.id, target.value);
      this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
    };

//  }
//}
```

Comment: I used .bind() to access to `id`, I hadn't thought to access to `id` with the target. You showed me a different vision, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In every iteration, you are overwriting `this.test` with the next listener. So at the end, `this.test` will contain the *last listener attached* and therefore it can only remove that one.

I can see two solutions here:

1. You could save *all* of the listener functions and then remove them again, mapping the element to the listener:

```js
this.objectInstance.on('selected', () => {
    this.test = new WeakMap();
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        const handler = this.fontFamilyHandler.bind(this, el.getAttribute('id'));
        this.test.set(el, handler);
        el.addEventListener('change', handler);
    }) 
});

this.objectInstance.on('deselected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        if (!this.test.has(el)) continue;
        el.removeEventListener('change', this.test.get(el));
    })
});
```

(Note: using just an array would not be stable because if the number of `<select>` elements in the document changes, the indices would get out of sync.)

(Note: It would also work with `Map` instead of `WeakMap`, but the latter allows earlier garbage-collection of any `<select>` element that gets removed from the DOM.)

2. Use the same function for all elements, instead of binding every time. Since you access the same element you are putting the listener on, and it's a `<select>` which means the `change` event will only ever come from the `<select>` itself as it cannot have any children that would be able to send `change` events, using `event.target.id` works too:

```js
const eventHandler = event => this.fontFamilyHandler(event.target.id, event);

this.objectInstance.on('selected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('change', eventHandler);
    }) 
});

this.objectInstance.on('deselected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        el.removeEventListener('change', eventHandler);
    })
});
```

(Note: `el.id` is easier than `el.getAttribute('id')` and does the same - see [`Element#id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).)

3. Or, you could use the `fontFamilyHandler` directly and change it to read the ID from the element itself.

```js
this.objectInstance.on('selected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('change', this.fontFamilyHandler);
    }) 
});

this.objectInstance.on('deselected', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((el) => {
        el.removeEventListener('change', this.fontFamilyHandler);
    })
});

// I removed the `key` argument here
this.fontFamilyHandler = evt => {
    this.objectInstance.set(evt.target.id, evt.target.value);
    this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```